# Determining Quartz Setup with Multiple Web Applications on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I have a server with multiple Tomcat instances and each contains about 10 application contexts.  I am considering using Quartz for some scheduling requirements we currently received.

I first thought that one Quartz server running and servicing all of the scheduling requests for each instance would be best, however it seems that most of the user guides bundle Quartz with each application.

My scheduler will have to run jobs on different databases for different contexts.

Does anyone out there have a similar set up?  Can anyone recommend how to use Quartz efficiently in the multiple instance, multiple context set up?   Will bundling a separate scheduler with each web app significantly increase the hardware resources I will need?  Any general advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did the following:

For each context we created a web service that exposes the functionality we want to execute.

We used another instance of tomcat to host the quartz server.  We looked at the command line server provided by Quartz and it worked well.  We just wanted an easy way for our server admin to start/stop the server and do automatic recovery on crash etc.  They are used to doing that with Tomcat so we opted to use tomcat to start Quartz.

In each context we configured the quartz client to use RMI to create Triggers and Jobs.   In the job details we included the web service url so the scheduler knows which context to execute the Job on.